# Disappearing TabBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController as root for my app with one of the tabs leading to a MapView with Pin annotations.  The MapView, itself, is embedded in a NavigationController.

When switching between Tabs all works fine apart from the fact that the TabBar disappears the second time the MapView is selected.  However, if a map pin is then selected, pushing on a Detail View, the TabBar reappears and subsequently seems to work correctly.

Any help on why this might be happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

- window RootViewController = UINavigationController

  - YourRootController (which implements TabBarController or subclasses)

Code (i.e. in AppDelegate):

```
YourRootCtrl *cont = [[YourRootCtrl alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cont];
navi.delegate = self;
[cont release];

[self.window setRootViewController:navi];
```

Comment: so you do it the other way round. Not the Navigation Controller in the TabBarController, but the other way round. I use it like that and it works like a charm

Comment: Fab1n, thanks for your response.

I have actually found the answer myself as elsewhere in the code I had stupidly set

 self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

and had forgotten to remove it.

Comment: I did the same dumb mistake and lost a couple of hours trying to solve it as well =/ Thanks for the tip!